# Iterate over an HashMap<String, ArrayList<Employee>> with Struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts-tags

I have a hashmap of employees per department like

Software

---

| Employee1 1001  |

---

| Employee2 1002  |

---

QA

---

| Employee3 1003  |

---

| Employee4 1004  |

---

I am using struts 2 "s:iterator" tag in JSP to iterate through hashmap and show the employees per department but I am getting the "ognl.NoConversionPossible" error.

"w:fieldSet" is my own custom tag that renders the header for department
"sb:table" is also custom tag to render the table

```
<s:iterator value="employeeMap">
    <w:fieldset name="%{getText(key)}">
    <sb:table rows="${value}" varStatus="varStatus">
        <sb:column header="Amount Type">
        <s:textfield name="values[${attr.varStatus.index}].employeeName"/>
        </sb:column>

        <sb:column header="Amount">
        <s:textfield name="values[${attr.varStatus.index}].employeeId"/>
        </sb:column>        
    </sb:table>
    </w:fieldset>
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: Did you try to use interfaces instead of classes.

Comment: No, I can't use the interfaces since there may be few more places where I need to apply same logic but on different classes.

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Dude, try with the interfaces. What you've answered to RomanC is a nonsense. Declare Map<String, List<Employee>> , then let the framework put hashMap and ArrayList as implementations

Comment: Andrea, Can you put some sample code about what you are talking here?